# Unity C# gameobjects remain in hierarchy after stopping the game - how to remove object clones from hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

i've got a scene with a gameobject X in it. On runtime i'll add some child gameobjects to X. When i hit the stop button the runtime generated objects will remain in the hierarchy under X.

I do Expect that after hitting stop the scene will be as it originally was before hitting play. Even if i try to Destroy() / DestroyImmediate() for each child in parent in OnApplicationQuit, the objects remain / duplicate with each start.

I didn't face this problem until 2 yesterday and didn't find a solution, maybe you guys can provide me with one.

Comment: What code did you change yesterday?

Comment: Are you using the `UnityEditor` namespace in any of your scripts? If so, which ones? And what are you using from that namespace?

Comment: @LeoBartkus that indeed was a very effiient question, since i changed seemingly meaningless stuff, i just reset my changes via git. Et voilàit - works again

thought this might have been some settings in the editor itself.

edit: sadly i don't know what changes it was now, since i didn't stage, only thing i remember was adding these objects to an 2D-array

Comment: @Ruzihm using UnityEditor;

Comment: Yes, but why are you using the `UnityEditor` namespace? Exactly which classes are you using from it? You are probably using something from the `UnityEditor` namespace incorrectly.

Comment: Specifically, please show us the code of where you instantiate the objects, and where you destroy them!

Answer (score 0):

@LeoBartkus advice was helpful, just reverted to older version.sry can't recreate how this happened- consider this as closed